# How To Click On Lock Image File Using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I want to click on two images i.e Files from Studio and Files to Studio provided in attachment for reference.
I tried multiple ways as using JavaScript,Action Class but i am not able to click on both options i.e Files From Studio and Files To Studio.

Before Click the image is locked as we click the file image icon gets open.
same for files to studio.

Can you please help me with solution of how i can click the Files From Studio and Files To Studio.

PFA of images with code present in console.

Thanks In Advance !!!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with javascript:

```
userName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Files to Studio']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", userName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with

```
//span[text()='Files to Studio']
```

xpath ?

like :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Files to Studio']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

You can try the same for `Files from Studio`, like `//span[text()='Files from Studio']`

Comment: I have used same logic but its not working I am getting below error on using.
                                                                     
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Files to Studio']").click() 
                                                                             
                                                                             {ElementClickInterceptedException}Message: element click intercepted: Element <span _ngcontent-ppf-c3="" class="mx-1 pr-1 activity-details-text-large-line-height">

Comment: have you launched browser in full screen mode ?

Comment: thanks for your response but it's work with the help of JavaScript.